# string substitution in statusline (change %F)

Tags: vimrc, statusline

My current statusline (in `.vimrc`) contains `%F` to show the current filename.

I want to perform a string substitution in `%F`.
More specifically I want to substitute `~/remotes/foo` -> `[foo]`

Examples:

- `~/remotes/foo/myproject/file.py`  -> `[foo]/myproject/file.py`
- `~/remotes/bar/other_project/main.py`  -> `[bar]/other_project/main.py`

In plain Vim I'd do something like `s/~\/remotes\/foo/[foo]`.

How to to that in `statusline` ?

I've tried some combinations like

```
:set statusline=%F
:set statusline=%{substitute(statusline, 'foo', 'bar', 'g')}
```

witout success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little sprinkling of `:help filename-modifiers`, `:help expand()` gives you the equivalent of `%F`:

```
:set statusline=%{expand('%:p:~')}
```

From there, you can perform the desired substitution:

```
set statusline=%{expand('%:p:~')->substitute('\\~\/remotes\/foo','[foo]','')}
```

Note that the resulting filename will always have either of those three forms:

- `/foo/bar/baz.txt` if outside of `~`,
- `~/foo/bar/baz` if inside of `~`,
- `[foo]/bar/baz` if inside of `~/remotes/foo`.

It is OK given your explicit requirements but, if you want more fine-tuning, you will have to write your own function. See also `:help fnamemodify()`.